# Nextauth - problem with refresh token and expire session

Tags: javascript, next.js, access-token, refresh-token, next-auth

Access Token is working good for
I have problem with refresh token and expire session
My backend use Oauth2
- always on expire access token(300s) i must use Refresh token

- if refresh token is not expire - get new access and refresh token, and must use new access and refresh token, not old refresh (not possible)
- if refresh token expire - i need signout - i know how do this on client, but not on server

I get new refresh token (his expiration is 14 day) but in cookies/session is old access and refresh. And expiration is not 300s but 30 days
[refresh token](https://carbon.now.sh/?bg=rgba%28171%2C+184%2C+195%2C+1%29&t=seti&wt=none&l=auto&ds=true&dsyoff=20px&dsblur=68px&wc=true&wa=true&pv=56px&ph=56px&ln=false&fl=1&fm=Hack&fs=14px&lh=133%25&si=false&es=2x&wm=false&code=export%2520async%2520function%2520refreshAccessToken%28token%29%2520%257B%250A%2509try%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509const%2520body%2520%253D%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509%2509client_id%253A%2520process.env.CLIENT_ID%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509client_secret%253A%2520process.env.CLIENT_SECRET%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509grant_type%253A%2520%27refresh_token%27%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509refresh_token%253A%2520token.refreshToken%252C%250A%2509%2509%257D%253B%250A%2509%2509const%2520refreshedToken%2520%253D%2520await%2520postUnauthorizeData%28body%29%253B%2520%252F%252F%2520POST%2520-%2520get%2520new%2520Refresh%2520and%2520Access%2520token%250A%2509%2509%2509%252F*%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2509refreshedToken%2520%253D%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509token_type%253A%2520%27Bearer%27%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509expires_in%253A%2520300%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509access_token%253A%2520%27eyJ0ADFDWDADeXAiOiJKV1QiLC...%27%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509refresh_token%253A%2520%27defASDADWD50200b7653f002c87ac5...%27%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509%257D%253B%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520*%252F%250A%250A%2509%2509if%2520%28refreshedToken%253F.error%29%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509%2509throw%2520refreshedToken%253B%250A%2509%2509%257D%250A%250A%2509%2509return%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509%2509...token%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509accessToken%253A%2520refreshedToken.access_token%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509accessTokenExpires%253A%2520Date.now%28%29%2520%252B%2520refreshedToken.expires_in%2520*%25201000%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509refreshToken%253A%2520refreshedToken.refresh_token%252C%250A%2509%2509%257D%253B%250A%2509%257D%2520catch%2520%28error%29%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509return%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509%2509...token%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509error%253A%2520%27RefreshAccessTokenError%27%252C%250A%2509%2509%257D%253B%250A%2509%257D%250A%257D)
[authorize](https://carbon.now.sh/?bg=rgba%28171%2C+184%2C+195%2C+1%29&t=seti&wt=none&l=auto&ds=true&dsyoff=20px&dsblur=68px&wc=true&wa=true&pv=56px&ph=56px&ln=false&fl=1&fm=Hack&fs=14px&lh=133%25&si=false&es=2x&wm=false&code=export%2520async%2520function%2520authorize%28credentials%29%2520%257B%250A%2509try%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509const%2520body%2520%253D%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509%2509grant_type%253A%2520%27password%27%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509client_id%253A%2520process.env.CLIENT_ID%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509client_secret%253A%2520process.env.CLIENT_SECRET%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509username%253A%2520credentials.email%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509password%253A%2520credentials.password%252C%250A%2509%2509%257D%253B%250A%2509%2509const%2520user%2520%253D%2520await%2520postUnauthorizeData%28body%29%253B%2520%252F%252F%2520send%2520email%2520and%2520password%2520to%2520get%2520Access%2520and%2520Refresh%2520token%250A%250A%2509%2509%252F*%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2509user%2520%253D%2520%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2522token_type%2522%253A%2520%2522Bearer%2522%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2522expires_in%2522%253A%2520300%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2522access_token%2522%253A%2520%2522eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC...%2522%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2522refresh_token%2522%253A%2520%2522def50200b7653f002c87ac5...%2522%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520*%252F%250A%2509%2509if%2520%28user%29%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509%2509const%2520userInfo%2520%253D%2520await%2520getUnauthorizeData%28%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%252F%252F%2520get%2520some%2520user%2520info%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509GET_ALL_USERS%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2560%253Ffilter%255Bname%255D%253D%2524%257Bcredentials.email%257D%2560%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509%29%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509return%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509data%253A%2520user%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509userInfo%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509%257D%253B%250A%2509%2509%257D%250A%2509%257D%2520catch%2520%28error%29%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509throw%2520new%2520Error%28error%29%253B%250A%2509%257D%250A%257D%250A)
[provider, callbacks,..](https://carbon.now.sh/?bg=rgba%28171%2C+184%2C+195%2C+1%29&t=seti&wt=none&l=auto&ds=true&dsyoff=20px&dsblur=68px&wc=true&wa=true&pv=56px&ph=56px&ln=false&fl=1&fm=Hack&fs=14px&lh=133%25&si=false&es=2x&wm=false&code=const%2520providers%2520%253D%2520%255B%250A%2509Providers.Credentials%28%257B%250A%2509%2509name%253A%2520%27Credentials%27%252C%250A%2509%2509credentials%253A%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509%2509username%253A%2520%257B%2520label%253A%2520%27Username%27%2520%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509%2509password%253A%2520%257B%2520label%253A%2520%27Password%27%2520%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509%257D%252C%250A%2509%2509authorize%252C%250A%2509%257D%29%252C%250A%255D%253B%250A%250Aconst%2520callbacks%2520%253D%2520%257B%250A%2509async%2520jwt%28token%252C%2520user%29%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509if%2520%28user%29%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509%2509token.accessToken%2520%253D%2520user%253F.data%253F.access_token%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509token.refreshToken%2520%253D%2520user%253F.data%253F.refresh_token%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509token.accessTokenExpires%2520%253D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509Date.now%28%29%2520%252B%2520user%253F.data%253F.expires_in%2520*%25201000%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509token.userName%2520%253D%2520user.userInfo.data%255B0%255D.attributes.display_name%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509token.userId%2520%253D%2520user.userInfo.data%255B0%255D.id%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509return%2520token%253B%250A%2509%2509%257D%250A%2509%2509%252F%252F%2520Return%2520previous%2520token%2520if%2520the%2520access%2520token%2520has%2520not%2520expired%2520yet%250A%2509%2509if%2520%28getActualTime%28%29%2520%253C%2520token.accessTokenExpires%29%2520return%2520token%253B%250A%250A%2509%2509%252F%252F%2520Access%2520token%2520has%2520expired%252C%2520try%2520to%2520update%2520it%250A%2509%2509return%2520refreshAccessToken%28token%29%253B%250A%2509%257D%252C%250A%250A%2509async%2520session%28session%252C%2520token%29%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509if%2520%28token%253F.error%29%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509%2509return%2520refreshAccessToken%28token%29%253B%250A%2509%2509%257D%250A%2509%2509if%2520%28token%29%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509%2509session.user%2520%253D%2520token.userName%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509session.userId%2520%253D%2520token.userId%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509session.accessToken%2520%253D%2520token.accessToken%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509session.error%2520%253D%2520token.error%253B%250A%2509%2509%2509session.expires%2520%253D%2520token.accessTokenExpires%253B%250A%2509%2509%257D%250A%2509%2509return%2520session%253B%250A%2509%257D%252C%250A%2509async%2520signIn%28session%29%2520%257B%250A%2509%2509return%2520session%253F.data%253F.access_token%2520%253F%2520true%2520%253A%2520false%253B%250A%2509%257D%252C%250A%257D%253B%250A%250Aconst%2520options%253A%2520NextAuthOptions%2520%253D%2520%257B%250A%2509providers%252C%250A%2509callbacks%252C%250A%257D%253B%250A%250Aexport%2520default%2520%28req%253A%2520NextApiRequest%252C%2520res%253A%2520NextApiResponse%29%2520%253D%253E%250A%2509NextAuth%28req%252C%2520res%252C%2520options%29%253B%250A)

Comment: Please add any relevant code to the question as a code block.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.